# How to send id and slug in django Url?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to make django urls suitable for the seo. I want to send Id and slug in the same url.I don't want to use slug I only want to show in the url.But i am getting an error. My model looks like this:

```
class Oyunlar(models.Model):
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    click_count = models.IntegerField()
    categories=models.ManyToManyField(Kategoriler,through='OyunlarKategoriler')
    base_price=models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    big_discount=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    en_ucuz = models.DecimalField(default=0,max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    popularite = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,default=0)
    discount_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=2)
    title_edit = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    steam_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    metacritic = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    recommendation = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    full_game = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    minimum = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    recommended = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    oyun_foto = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)) # This field type is a guess.
    windows = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    mac = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    linux = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'oyunlar'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('<int:game_id>/<slug:slug>/',views.oyun,name='detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
def oyun(request,slug,game_id):
    print(slug)
    oyun=Oyunlar.objects.get(pk=game_id)
    comments=Comments.objects.filter(oyunlar=oyun)
    game_price=GamePrice.objects.filter(game_id=game_id).order_by('price')
    categories = OyunlarKategoriler.objects.filter(game=oyun).values_list('category_id', flat=True)
    benzer = Oyunlar.objects.filter(categories__category_id__in=categories, platform=oyun.platform).order_by('-click_count').distinct()[:4]
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cf = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        print('burda')
        if cf.is_valid():
            print('valid')
            text = request.POST.get('text')
            comment = Comments.objects.create(oyunlar=oyun, user=request.user, text=text)
            comment.save()
            return redirect(oyun.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        cf = CommentForm()


    return render(request,'product-simple.html',{'oyun':oyun,'game_price':game_price,'benzer':benzer,'comment_form':cf,'comments':comments})
```

**Helper Tag**

```
@register.filter
def slug(value):
    return slugify(unidecode(value))
```

**html**

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' i.game_id i.title|slug %}"
```

But I am getting an error:

**Error**

```
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(32147,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<game_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Comment: maybe first check `{% i.game_id %} {% i.title %}`  to see what you have in variables. it seems you have tuple `(32147,)` and you should use `[0]` to get first element from tuple. Probably `i.game_id[0]`

Comment: Hi, I can see i.title in the page but when it comes to sending it,django cannot see the variable.

Comment: you could check `{% i.title|slug %}` and you should check first in HTML what you get in `<a href="...">`. You could check also some text hardcoded in URL to see if problem makes other text - `<a href="{% url 'detail' i.game_id 'text' %}`

Comment: I don't know if it is important that you have variables in different order in `def oyun(request,slug,game_id):` and `path('<int:game_id>/<slug:slug>/'`